# MbUnit and DataDrivenTests how to run single Row&

Tags: mbunit

I'm trying to move big project from NUnit to MbUnit(Gallio). And I've big(for me) problem in DataDriven Tests(
Current MbUnit example Gallio exploring as single test case.

```
[Test]
[Row("111qqq", true)]
[Row("qqq111", true)]
[Row("*", false)]
public void TestIsCorrect(string a_source, bool a_bRes)
```

see( http://files.rsdn.ru/68665/mbunitrow.png )

Therefore I cannot run single row. Any know any solution of current problem?
I want, that Gallio exploring MbUnit DataDriven test, like as NUnit.

see( http://files.rsdn.ru/68665/nunitrow.png )